# Pandas groupby + ifelse + add new column back to original df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like the following. The rightmost column is my desired column:

```
Group   Value1  Value2   TargetColumn   
1        1         2         0
1        2         2         1
1        3         3         1
1        4         4         1
2        6         9         0
2        7         5         0
2        8         6         0
2        9         7         0
```

If value of `Value2` in a given row is higher than value of `Value1` in the previous row, then return 1 else 0. I want perform this ifelse operation grouped by `Group` and then add  `TargetColumn` back to the original dataframe.

I am generally trying the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'Value1': [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9], 'Value2': [2,2,3,4,9,5,6,7]})

 df['TargetColumn'] = df.groupby(['Group'])(np.where(['Value2'] > ['Value1'].shift() , 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare by [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html) (`>`) column `Value1` by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html)ed column `Value1`, last cast boolean mask to integers for `True/False` to `1/0`:

```
df['TargetColumn'] = df['Value2'].gt(df.groupby('Group')['Value1'].shift()).astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['TargetColumn'] = np.where(df['Value2'].gt(df.groupby('Group')['Value1'].shift()), 1, 0)
```

---

```
print (df)

   Group  Value1  Value2  TargetColumn
0      1       1       2             0
1      1       2       2             1
2      1       3       3             1
3      1       4       4             1
4      2       6       9             0
5      2       7       5             0
6      2       8       6             0
7      2       9       7             0
```

Comment: Thank you for the great solution. I am assuming `pandas.Series.lt` is for less than.  What do I use for  less than or equal to (<=) and  greater than or equal to(>=)?

Comment: Sure, need `le` and `ge` - [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.lt.html)
[`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html)
[`le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.le.html)
[`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ge.html)
[`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html)
[`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html)